# Can I make wget retrieve just a single folder (and it children) but also save and relink external images?

Tags: wget

I am trying to download a just the /publications/ folder of a site www.idea.int to include on a USB drive for offline viewing.

I have tried:

```
wget --recursive --no-remove-listing -l inf --no-parent --adjust-extension 
 --no-cookies --convert-links --page-requisites http://www.idea.int/publications/
```

which correctly only saves /publications/ and subfolders. But we have images on these pages that are retrieved from static0.idea.int and these are not download nor relinked, even then I have the `--page-requisites` flag on.

So then I tried:

```
wget --recursive --no-remove-listing -l inf --no-parent --adjust-extension 
   --no-cookies --convert-links --page-requisites   
   --span-hosts --domains=idea.int http://offline.idea.int/publications/
```

hoping that the `--span-hosts` would allow the images to be downloaded and relinked by the `convert-links` step. However, this ignores the `--no-parent` option and basically downloads the entire www.idea.int site.

Is there a way I can download all HTML pages inside /publications/ plus all image resources included in those pages (even on another domain) and relink them for offline viewing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite late, but...

```
wget -p -k -r -np http://www.idea.int/publications/
```

...should be the correct command here.

-p (or --page-requisites) gets all images, etc. needed to display HTML page.

-k (or --convert-links) makes links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to local files.

-r (or --recursive) specifies that you want a recursive download (downloads all children)

-np (or --no-parent) prevents it from ascending to the parent directory.

It looks like what you were missing was the -p flag.

Note: some of the text above was taken from wget --help